# Deriving diffusion coefficients from Newtonian mechanics of Lennard-Jones phases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, many-body, kinetic-theory, non-equilibrium

The diffusion coefficient is known in the traditional physical literature as an empirical parameter of Fick's law. Here the observation is that spatial gradients of densities are suppressed by a rate proportional to the gradient of the density, and the diffusion constant is identified as the constant of proportionality. An other empirical definition is the identification of the constant of proportionality between the mean squared displacement and the square root of time of colloids. One insight of the paper on Brownian motion by Einstein was that these two definitions are consistent with each other.

However in the last decades we additionally learned from the computational physical literature that if we take N classical particles interacting via Lennard-Jones pair forces, we consistently observe the linear MSD vs square root of time dependence.

However I never came across an attempt to derive this result analytically, that is, for a set of known LJ parameters (sigma, epsilon, T, V, N,..), is it possible to analytically show or derive this linear correlation ?

Comment: Related (LJ potential, same user): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/345015/226902 See also (LJ equation of state): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/472927/226902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an extremely difficult problem and still very far from being solved. For a recent result in this direction, see [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-015-0593-9) (there are also several subsequent ones by the same group of authors). Their paper addresses (mathematically rigorously) a much simpler problem: consider a gas of hard spheres evolving according to Newtonian mechanics. Mark one of the spheres and follow its trajectory. They prove, in the Boltzmann-Grad limit, the convergence of the latter to a Brownian motion and determine the diffusion coefficient.

Comment: As a follow up I would like to ask if you are aware of literature from the mathematics or mathematical physics communities that attempt to derive solid/liquid/gas phase transitions within this same setting ? I have been searching for this and never found some established well-cited proofs.

Comment: There is [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1004591218510) (see also the corresponding [PRL](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.80.4701)) that establishes a liquid/gas phase transition in a system of this type. Unfortunately, the technique employed does not allow for a hard core and the authors had to use a 4-body repulsive potential on top of the 2-body interaction to guarantee stability. In any case, that's the best that is rigorously known (apart from some minor extensions later; just look at the papers citing this one), as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know of any even marginally-realistic model in which a liquid/solid phase transition has been established rigorously (on the other hand, there are some negative results proving that you cannot have such a transition in two-dimensional systems; this is much easier).